# Copying between VARIANT and _variant_t

Tags: c++, visual-c++, com, ole, variant

I'm fairly certain that I can safely do:

```
void funcA(VARIANT &V,_variant_t &vt)
{
    vt = V;
}
```

But what about the other way around:

```
void funcB(VARIANT &V,_variant_t &vt)
{
    V = vt;
}
```

I've been seeing some REALLY weird behaviour in my app which I put down to COM-related threading issues. But then I got wondering if I was screwing up memory using variants wrongly. In funcB, the VARIANT V is part of a safe-array being prepared for a COM call. With my V=vt line, am I doing a shallow copy which will break things when the same variant gets deallocated twice?

I really like _variant_t and avoiding all the ::VariantXXX methods, is there a neat way to use _variant_t in funcB to automate the copying?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, yes, by using the assignment operator the way you do in `funcB()` you invoke shallow copying only (you might want to look into oaidl.h to see the `VARIANT` definition - it has no user-defined assignment operator and therefore shallow copying is done by the compiler).

This gets you into undefined behaviour if the other variant you copied from is cleared before you access the shallow copy (for example, if the variant type was `VT_UNKNOWN` the object pointed to could simply be destroyed after setting the reference count to 0 by calling the `IUnknown::Release()`).

`_variant_t` will not help you much since it has no methods for copying to another object - see comutil.h for class definition - it only copies from another object to itself.

The easiest way would be to use `VariantCopy()`. Not sure if the safearray will be initialized when you deal with it. If it is initialized with each element having `VT_EMPTY` you can just call `VariantCopy()`. Otherwise first call `VariantInit()` on the destination to initialize the destination. Calling `VariantCopy()` for a destination containing random uninitialized data can lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: You'll probably get undefined behaviour in any case due to double deletion (in case of `BSTR`) and dangling pointers (in case of `IUnknown`) when both the safearray and the `_varaint_t` are destroyed.

Comment: Calling VariantClear on an uninitialized VARIANT will also break. Make sure the VARIANT is initialized using VariantInit before attempting to copy to it.

Answer (score 3):

If the `VARIANT` contains an object or a `BSTR` you **will** run into trouble when you deallocate the safearray since safearray deallocation will free the resource which it doesn't own. So when either the `_variant_t` or the safearray is destroyed the other will have a reference to a deallocated object.

For example if the `VARIANT` contains a pointer to `IUnknown` you'll mess up the reference count by calling `Release` more times than `AddRef`, if it contains a `BSTR` you'll just copy the pointer and not allocate a new string for the new variable.

This is why you should use `VariantCopy`, if you want to avoid `Variant*` methods (for a reason I can't understand) this can be done with `_variant_t::Detach()`

```
void funcB(VARIANT &V,_variant_t &vt)
{
    _variant_t temp = vt;
    V = temp.Detach();
    // or in one line V = _variant_t(vt).Detach(); 
}
```